# Using PL2303HX module to program PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm very new to the electronics stuff. I've spent most of my discovering things so far, however there is something that I'm stuck on.

I want to get a PIC18F4550 to begin with, and I'm wondering if I can use a PL2303HX USB to TTL UART module to connect the chip to the programmer ([image here](http://www.dipmicro.com/img/1/BTE-PL2303HX-MOD-2.jpg)).

If yes, would I need to connect RXD to RX/DT and TXD to TX/CK pins?

Yes, I know PICKit exists. I'm trying to find a way around that.

Comment: Why do you want a way around using a programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at the datasheet for the PIC18F4550 ([link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632e.pdf)). It does support EUSART (Enhanced Universal Sync/Async Receiver Transmitter), thats what they call it I guess. You would simply have to setup transmit and receive (pg 244, 245) properly. Setup your baud, enable transmit/receive, etc. Then hookup your PL2303HX and you should be set.  Specifically pin-26 and pin-25 for the 40-pin pdip diagram.

Some advice seeing that you are new to this stuff. Get a microcontroller with as much timers as you can afford (higher bit timers i.e. 16-bits are ideal). Also be careful of the suppliers you buy from, some of them sell after market parts that may have different vendor/device IDs that will render them useless unless you use their programming software. Also buy 2 of those TTL receivers, you will need it when the other burns out.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked was to avoid importing a PICKit from the US, however it took shorter than the answer I could get here. I have several PICs by now (PIC18s, dsPIC24s and PIC32s) and am working on my quadcopter project.

Comment: Wow, when I first started with microcontrollers I actually started building a quadcopter myself. I use mainly AVRs so I really cant say much about PICs however from what I have seen, they are all very similar.

Comment: To be honest -- I don't really care about the hardware part of it, I just want to write an autopilot for it!